# Include helper module in Capybara specs

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am writing specs for Capyabara in rails. Here i found article to share common code between the feature specs. link : http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara

But when I use its module method 'sign_in' in my rails spec it's giving error "uninitialized constant sign_in'"

```
describe "GET /" do
  ## include Features::SessionHelpers

  before :each do
    sign_in
  end
     ....
```

How can I import this helper module in my rspec correctly? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper methods can be included using `RSpec.configure`.

Assuming you want the helper methods available to all examples, add the following to your spec helper (or at least somewhere outside the example group):

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include Features::SessionHelpers
end
```

For more examples, such as only adding the helper methods to specific examples, see the [Relish's helper method page](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module).